# Change xml syntax highlighting in Kate

Tags: kate

I have just downloaded and installed Kubuntu and I was using Kate to modify XML files.  I don't like the pink color of the attribute values.  How could I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings/Configure Kate .../Fonts & Colors you can change any color (and other appearance features) of Kate.

Select the Highlighting Text Styles tab and then the Markup/XML scheme. There you can change all colors for XML files.